# Count the number of unique tuples for each key in a dictionary of lists in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

ill start off with an example first:

```
lists_dict = { 1: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')],
2: [('64', 's'), ('0', 'r'), ('0', 'M')], 
3: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')], 
4: [('64', 'I'), ('0', 'S'), ('0', 'N')] }
```

Here is how a dictionary could look like for my task, and what my goal is that I want to compare each element in the list with the element in the other list that has the same index, if the element is not present in any other lists whatsoever, then that key is going to get another value that is going to be an int. For every extra unique tuple present, the int is going to increase with +1.
So in our case the output would be the following:

```
1: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')],0 #(no unique)
2: [('64', 's'), ('0', 'r'), ('0', 'M')],2 #(two unique tuples)
3: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')],0 #(no unique
4: [('64', 'I'), ('0', 'S'), ('0', 'N')], 3 #(unique, no other list have these values)
```

Now this is just an example, the dictionary has 400 keys and the amount of elements in each list is 22(22 tuples with two values in them)

I have been trying to solve this but I have gotten nowhere, is there any help I could get?

Ive tried iterating through the first element in every list and compared them then, but it felt like it would be a ineffecient way of solving this problem.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: lists_dict=
1: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')],0
2: [('64', 's'), ('0', 'r'), ('0', 'M')],2
3: [('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')],0
4: [('64', 'I'), ('0', 'S'), ('0', 'N')], 3

Comment: @rand_coder123, the expected output does not look valid

Comment: this is how i think the problem should be attempted at first(psuedo_code):
for i in lists_dict: 
    for j in range(len(amount_of_keys)):
        lists_dict[i][0] 
but this got me through the first element of every list from the keys. But I literally do not know what to do next. Im not looking for code solving the problem but guidance to where I might start

Comment: @rand_coder123 Please edit your question to provide answers to questions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Counter class to determine the number of times each tuple is present in the whole dictionary.  Then build the result by counting tuples in each lists that have a count of exactly one.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(t for lst in lists_dict.values() for t in enumerate(lst))
result = { k:(lst,sum(counts[t]==1 for t in enumerate(lst))) 
           for k,lst in lists_dict.items() }

print(result)

{1: ([('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')], 0),
 2: ([('64', 's'), ('0', 'r'), ('0', 'M')], 2),
 3: ([('64', 'R'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'M')], 0),
 4: ([('64', 'I'), ('0', 'S'), ('0', 'N')], 3)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the main dictionary items. For each dictionary element, get a list of all the other dictionary elements. Then for each tuple in the current item, test if any of the corresponding tuples in the other elements matches. Then use `sum()` to count how many of them are unique in this test.

```
result = {}
for key, value in lists_dict.items():
    other_values = [l for key2, l in lists_dict.items() if key2 != key]
    result[key] = sum(not any(value[i] == l[i] for l in other_values) 
                      for i in range(len(value)))
```

Comment: Is there anyway you could also add the index position of the tuple at the same time? So that we know its the "fourth" tuple that is the unique one of the key?

Comment: Use a list comprehension instead of summing. `[i for i in range(len(value)) if not any(value[i] == l[i] for l in other_values)]`